# correctly checking file existence while multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, file-exists

I have a function, `myfunc`, which is called in parallel processing. When I make several processes share the same destination folder, all of them call `myfunc` in parallel and check the existence of the destination folder. If it already existed, no problem. However, if the folder did not exist prior to launching the script, then the first process will enter the if block and create the folder. On the other hand, there will be another process that will enter the very same if block "almost" at the same time, will find the folder does not exist, and will try to create it, while the first process is actually creating it or has already done it. So at some point there will be an `OSError` telling the folder already exists.

Is there a clean way to deal with this issue while multiprocessing? I am thinking of taking care of the destination folder out of the function `myfunc`, before launching my processes. It would be nice however to find a solution using multiprocessing, for the sake of knowledge.

```
import os, sys

def myfunc(file_names, destination=None, file_permission=None, verbose=False):
    absPath = os.path.abspath(file_names[0])
    baseName = os.path.basename(absPath)
    dirName = os.path.dirname(absPath)


    destination_folder = "/default/destination" if destination is None \
        else os.path.abspath(destination)

    if not os.path.isdir(destination_folder):
        os.mkdir(destination_folder)
        os.chmod(destination_folder, file_permission)
        if verbose:
            print "Created directory", destination_folder
```

Comment: Well, catch the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Checking for existence of a file/folder and taking action based on the result is fundamentally wrong in most cases, because even if you are not multiprocessing, you don't know what else is running on the computer. It is also difficult to guarantee that someone else won't later run multiple copies of your process, even if you didn't originally intend that.

The most robust method is to always try to create the folder, and silently ignore the "but that already exists" error. (Do not ignore other errors, such as "but you don't have that permission"!) This would still be the best way to do things even if you did a single check prior to starting the multiprocessing.

Comment: Do you think a combination of catching exception and lock should be used? I actually don't know which answer is the most adequate between yours and th3an0maly's.

Comment: To be robust, you must catch the exception. In the general case, even if your locks are perfect, another program may unexpectedly change files or folders out from under you. Once you've done that, you can evaluate whether also using locks or conditionals adds value. There definitely are places where they will be useful, but I do not think this is one of those places. Once you catch the exception, the lock adds extra complexity to this solution without providing any additional safety.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Lock` from the `threading` module for solving concurrency issues:

```
import os, sys
from threading import Lock

def myfunc(lock, ...):
    ... do stuff as usual ...

    with lock:
        destination_folder = "/default/destination" if destination is None \
            else os.path.abspath(destination)

    ... do everything else as usual ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_lock = Lock()
    myfunc(my_lock, ...)
```

Comment: And if using `multiprocessing` (as per the title), then the equivalent `multiprocessing.Lock`.